# DataGrid.ColumnWidth="*" not working in a ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer

I have a `DataGrid` with `ColumnWidth="*"` in a `ScrollViewer` with `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`. Unfortunately this combination doesn't seem to work well. While the `DataGrid` spans properly over the full window width the columns are super small (`MinWidth`). If I change `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Disabled` it works but I lose the desired `ScrollViewer` behavior.

Minimal Working Example:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Sandbox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Sandbox"
        Title="MainWindow"
        x:Name="ThisControl">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 3" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 4" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Why is this happening and how can I work around it?

Comment: try to use 2* instead *

Comment: @MahdiFarhani That doesn't do anything.

Comment: the main problem is ScrollViewer, but let me find the reason. when you remove the ScrollViewer every thing is good.

Comment: @MahdiFarhani As I said it's the HorizontalScrollBarVisibilit that is causing issues. It's enough to set it to Disabled and it works. I would like to have that behavior, though.

Comment: You could make your DataGrid width equal to the ScrollViewer width, but when the vertical scrollbar appears it would also show the horizontal scrollbar

Comment: @Pikoh But then I need a set Width.

Comment: not exactly. Try this and see what i mean: `<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}},
Path=ActualWidth}"
>`

Comment: @Pikoh Nice idea but as you mentioned now it will always show the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Anyway, I don't see the point in a Datagrid inside a ScrollViewer. DataGrid has its own Scroll. The problem you see is because as the Datagrid is inside a ScrollViewer, it has virtually infinite space to expand,so it can calculate widths

Comment: @Pikoh It works when I bind it to ViewportWidth instead of ActualWidth, thanks! Feel free and post that as an answer.

Comment: Yes,i forgot ViewportWidth. I've added it as an answer, glad it works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you see is because as the Datagrid is inside a ScrollViewer, it has virtually infinite space to expand,so it can't calculate widths. For this to work you can bind the DataGrid Width to the ScrollViewer ViewportWidth, as this:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" 
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}, Path=ViewportWidth}">
```